# How to make Windows Defener trust my applications at company level

Tags: windows-defender

In my company, I made some Windows form applications for internal use.

They're some client-server applications, client is C# windows form (.NET4.6), server is ASP.NET REST API, publish using ClickOnce.

Everytime user start application, Windows Defender show up and say that "unrecognized...".

How could I make it recognize and trust my applications?

Tell user to disable Windows defender on their client is not allowed so I need a solution at company level

[image: Windows Defender blocked my apps]

Comment: Why is your app not signed?

Comment: Signing applications has been discussed lots of times on [sf].

Comment: The easiest way is to sign your application. SmartScreen needs some kind of basis to rely on when evaluating unknown apps/apps used only by a small subset of users. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/10/13/stranger-danger-introducing-smartscreen-application-reputation/